# Create numpy array consisting of multiple images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have multiple images (they are of the same size) which I want to put in a numpy array so that the result is a array of dimension `(len(img_list), 1)`.

```
img_list = [img, img, img]
img.shape, type(img_list), len(img_list)
```

> ((1056, 2034, 3), list, 3)

My main problem is that the following happens when I use `numpy.array()`:

```
a = np.array(img_list, dtype=np.object)
type(a), a.dtype, a.shape, a.ndim
```

> (numpy.ndarray, dtype('O'), (3, 1056, 2034, 3), 4)

Notice the dimensions is four, instead of two as expected.

So far the best method I found to get dimension `(len(img_list), 1)` is to create an empty array of the desired dimension and then use broadcasting:

```
a = np.empty((3,1), dtype=np.object)
type(a), a.dtype, a.shape, a
```

> (numpy.ndarray, dtype('O'), (3, 1), array([[None], [None], [None]], dtype=object))

```
a[:,0] = img_list
type(a), a.dtype, a.shape
```

> (numpy.ndarray, dtype('O'), (3, 1))

This yield the desired dimension.

Is there a numpy function that can do that directly without creating an empty array first?

---

## EDIT

I thought using `numpy.hstack` or `numpy.stack` should do the trick but this results in the "wrong" dimension:

```
a_stacked = np.stack(img_list)
type(a_stacked), a_stacked.dtype, a_stacked.shape, a.ndim
```

> (numpy.ndarray, dtype('uint8'), (3, 1056, 2034, 3), 4)

To clarify: I would like `a.ndim == 2` and not `a.ndim == 4`. In other words, `a.shape` should be `(3,1)` and not `(3, 1056, 2034, 3)`.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to keep the number of dimensions to be 2? Probably there's a better solution to your more general problem.

Comment: Thais seems like an XY problem.  I can't imagine  reason for wanting an object array of same-shaped numerical arrays.  `dtype('O')` arrays break most `numpy` methods, and require treating them like large, slow-performing lists.

Comment: In my problem the first dimension should represent the samples (number of images - image samples). The shape of the second dimension shows the number of features. At the start of a scikit-learn processing pipeline I want to operate on the image feature as a whole. I couldn't find a fast numpy method that iterates over the first dimension (samples) and applies an operation to the rest (image feature). Please correct me if there is a more appropriate way.

Comment: @DanielF, I wouldn't go this way if I could use vectorization. However, the functions I am dealing with, mostly operate on single images. To speed things up I would have to change the functions first to operate on speedy numpy arrays.

Comment: Then make it a nested list of arrays.  It'll be faster an you'll have direct access to list comprehension tools.

Comment: Yes, lists could be an option. The only problem with lists is that the standard FeatureUnion class (and most other classes) of scikit-learn returns only numpy arrays. "Unfortunately", you won't get the type out that you put into scikit-learn transformers :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but wouldn't `numpy.stack()` do? That's how I usually create batches of images.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `numpy.stack()`, I tried that too but the output regarding `shape` and `ndim` is not what I want. I've added the desired output shape and dimension.